# How to route in laravel with anchor tag?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Below is my code in web.php

```
$api->get('admin/views/query/new_query', 'AdminViewsController@answer_to_query');
```

In my controller:

```
public function answer_to_query() {
    return view('admin.query.new_query');
  }
```

In my view:

```
<div class="btn-group">                             
    <a href="#/query_list/answer_to_query" class="btn btn-xs green" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" ui-sref="querydtlsController"> View<i class="fa fa-angle"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

I dont know how to call my method `answer_to_query` from above page to display my `new_query` page.

Comment: have yout tried removing the # from the beginning of your link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `url()` helper if you don't want to name the route for some reason:

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/views/query/new_query') }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

Web.php

```
$api->get('admin/views/query/new_query', 'AdminViewsController@answer_to_query')->name('answer_to_query_view');
```

View.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('answer_to_query_view')}}" class="btn btn-xs green" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" ui-sref="querydtlsController"> View<i class="fa fa-angle"></i>
```

I prefer using named routes since it is much easier to organize instead of always making the link manually

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes